# Value of type 'UIAccessibilityNotifications' (aka 'UInt32') has no member 'screenChanged'

Tags: ios, swift

Getting the error for the code below after updating Swift. I tried a couple variants with no luck?

UIAccessibility.post(notification: UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification.screenChanged,
                                    argument: bottomContainer);
  }

tried: UIAccessibility.post(notification: UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification, screenChanged,
                                    argument: bottomContainer);
  }
and 
UIAccessibility.post(notification: UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotificationscreenChanged,
                                    argument: bottomContainer);
  }

Always get back to this error: Value of type 'UIAccessibilityNotifications' (aka 'UInt32') has no member 'screenChanged'

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  You should be using something like `UIAccessibility.post(notification: UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification, argument: x)` where x is a string to be spoken or an accessibility element to move to.

Comment: This is an imagepicker controller and Im trying to have the notification post back when the screen changes from the bottom window.

Comment: Ok,  but I still don't understand where you are getting `screenChanged` from. You can't post that. It appears to be part of some enumeration. My comment and the documentation for `UIAccessibilityLayoutChangeNotification` show how you can post the notification.

Answer (score 2):

Try this!

```
 UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification, bottomContainer)
```